# Bootstrap 4 margin:auto and text-center doesnt center my paragraph

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to center a paragraph in my project but i couldn't

I tried `margin:0px auto;` and `text-center` features but they didn't work

```
<div class="row text-center">
   <p>
Daha fazla bilgi edinmek için veya sorularınız için aşağıdaki iletişim formunu kullanarak bize ulaşabilirsiniz.<br>
Mutlaka 24 saat içinde size geri dönüş sağlanacaktır.
  </p>

</div>
```

And Css Code:

```
.takim-content p {

    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#777;
    margin:50px auto;   

}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I used container `div` for these circles and `col-sm-6` class

As well, I want to bring closer these circles and I tried `padding-left` and `padding-right` with same values but it is causing wrong result for responsive display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your first problem just use `justify-content-center`

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
   <p>
Daha fazla bilgi edinmek için veya sorularınız için aşağıdaki iletişim formunu kullanarak bize ulaşabilirsiniz.<br>
Mutlaka 24 saat içinde size geri dönüş sağlanacaktır.
  </p>
</div>
```

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

To solve your second problem. You can use `float-right` for first circle and `float-left` for second circle.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"><span class="circle float-right"></span></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"><span class="circle float-left"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is aligned center, you can see because the second line isn't left justified. The issue is that the paragraph or div holding the text isn't the correct width. There are a few solutions depending on what your desired visual is.

Depending on where your width is coming from, you should be able to set the width of the `div` and `p` to 100%:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to center the elements, it looks like you already have `margin: 50px auto;` on the `p`. Try setting it on the div instead:

```
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note: Be sure to add these fixes to unique classes or id's so that you don't add them to every instance of a `div`, `p`, or bootstrap class like `row`.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Work for me**

`<div class="row justify-content-md-center">  your paragraph </div>`

Answer (score 0):

just add justify-content-center in div which has class row